# Use query parameter like "?name=" from url in a template

Tags: python, django, templates

Django debug toolbar shows me in GET parameters that I have a variable 'name' in my get parameters, which is normal.

I'd like to get this 'name' value to fill the form placeholder.

I've tried `{{ view.get.name }}` or `{{ request.name }}` or... `{{ name }}` with no success.

Comment: `{{request.GET.name}}`?

Comment: OMG ! I forgot ```get``` is case sensitive !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python is case sensitive language and the get parameters are in the [GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), so you just need:

```
{{request.GET.name}}
```